# Active Directory: How to get a list of users according to a specific Organization unit

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for some professionnals for a bit of help...
I'm quite new in development, and I'm working on my first project at work.
The goal is to automatically delete the non-needed accounts in the active directory (in a specific OU (org. unit) of course).
For this to be done, I need to get the list of the accounts.  This works fine.
I'm working with three tiers (Data Access, Business and GUI).

I wrote a 'GetOU' function in the data access layer, wich get the OU from the Active Directory.  The differents OU are listed in a ComboBox.
When the user changes the OU in the combobox, I would like to get back the value of the selection, and pass it to my Data access layer, so, in a GetMembers function, I can select the members from the specified OU and throw it back to a datagrid.

I don't know if this is clear enough
Here's what i wrote till now:
Data Access:

```
public static DataTable GetMembers()
    {
        DataTable membersDt = new DataTable();
        DataSet membersDs = new DataSet();
        DataColumn column;

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.ColumnName = "ID";
        membersDt.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.ColumnName = "First Name";
        membersDt.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.ColumnName = "Last Name";
        membersDt.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.ColumnName = "Logon";
        membersDt.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.ColumnName = "ManagerDN";
        membersDt.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.ColumnName = "Logon Manager";
        membersDt.Columns.Add(column);

        membersDs.Tables.Add(membersDt);

        DataRow row;
        String dom = "OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
        DirectoryEntry directoryObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dom);
        int i = 1;

        foreach (DirectoryEntry child in directoryObject.Children)
        {
            row = membersDt.NewRow();
            membersDt.Rows.Add(row);
            row["ID"] = i++;

            if (child.Properties["givenName"].Value == null)
            {
                row["First Name"] += "Group Logon";
            }
            else 
            {
                row["First Name"] = child.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
            }
            row["Last Name"] = child.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
            row["Logon"] = child.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();

            if (child.Properties["Manager"].Value == null)
            {
                row["ManagerDN"] += "Unknown Manager";
            }
            else
            {
                row["ManagerDN"] = child.Properties["Manager"].Value.ToString();
            }
            String uManager = row["ManagerDN"].ToString();
            DirectoryEntry UserManager = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + uManager);
            if (child.Properties["Manager"].Value == null)
            {
                row["Logon manager"] += "Unknown Manager";
            }
            else
            {
                row["Logon Manager"] = UserManager.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        return membersDt;
    }

 public static DataTable GetOUList()
    {
        //Creation du filtre de recherche
        String dom = "OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
        DirectoryEntry directoryObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dom);
        DirectorySearcher ouSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryObject);
        ouSearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=OrganizationalUnit)";

        //Tri ascendant de la liste sortie
        SortOption sortedOuList = new SortOption();
        sortedOuList.PropertyName = "OU";
        sortedOuList.Direction = SortDirection.Ascending;
        ouSearcher.Sort = sortedOuList;

        //Recherche des OU présentes dans 'string dom'
        DataTable OuDt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn column;

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.ColumnName = "OuName";
        OuDt.Columns.Add(column);

        DataRow row;
        foreach (SearchResult result in ouSearcher.FindAll())
        {
            row = OuDt.NewRow();
            OuDt.Rows.Add(row);
            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
            row["OuName"] = dirEntry.Properties["ou"].Value;
        }
        return OuDt;
    }
```

Business:

```
public static DataTable GetMembers()
    {
        try
        {
            return DAL.Classes.DataProvider.GetMembers();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error getting MemberList: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
    }

public static DataTable GetOu()
    {
        try
        {
            return DAL.Classes.DataProvider.GetOUList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error getting Ou: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

GUI:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Display des OU dans le combo
        OuCBox.DataSource = ToBeDeleted.BLL.Classes.MembersManager.GetOu();
        OuCBox.DisplayMember = "OuName";

    }

    private void getListBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembersDG.DataSource = ToBeDeleted.BLL.Classes.MembersManager.GetMembers();
        MembersDG.Columns["ManagerDN"].Visible = false;
        MembersDG.Columns["ID"].Width = 35;            
    }
```

So I can display the memberList if the string 'dom' is fully complete.
What I wanna do is:
Selection of one OU in the OuCBox, return the value to the data access layer so I can make a FindAll() on this specific OU.

Any help appreciated !
Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, it's working fine now with:

```
   string selectedOu = ((System.Data.DataRowView)OuCBox.SelectedValue)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Add the selected ou to the `dom` variable. Don't filter on it.

Comment: Thank you jgauffin, but when I do that, the value of my selectedOu string is: system.data.dataRowView